# Animate or scroll EditText to top of screen

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-animation, android-scrollview

I have a DialogFragment, where is a ScrollView with some EditText fields. If the user press on the last one, it should be moved to top of the dialog, right under the title.
If I just scroll to this field with scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, view), it just appears over the soft keyboard, but other fields over this last one are still shown.
If I make the visibility of all fields above "GONE", it works fine, but the user can't scroll back, but I need it.
I don't know if it is possible on Android at all. Can anybody please help me? I spent three days on this problem but could not find the solution. Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT: screenshots
this is what I have:
[image]

and what I need:

[image]

Comment: Can you add screenshots? I'm having trouble understanding what the issue is exactly.